# VistaFolderBrowserDialog does not start with the correct folder

Tags: c#, wpf, folderbrowserdialog

I would like to use a Folder Browse Dialog for WPF, but there does not seem to be such an essential class for `WPF`.

Some recommend to use `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog` but this is a really awful dialog.

I tried [Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.VistaFolderBrowserDialog](http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/):

```
Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.VistaFolderBrowserDialog dlg = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog();
dlg.SelectedPath = path;
dlg.ShowDialog();
```

but setting the `SelectedPath` does not set the start folder when the Dialog opens which is essential for my program.

How can I get `VistaFolderBrowserDialog` to open in the correct folder?

Comment: I don't think Microsoft has changed anything in System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog since 90s.... It really is aweful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the Codeplex project [WPF Native Folder Browser](http://wpffolderbrowser.codeplex.com/):

```
WPFFolderBrowser.WPFFolderBrowserDialog dlg = new WPFFolderBrowserDialog();
dlg.InitialDirectory = path;
bool? pathWasSelected = dlg.ShowDialog();
string selectedPath = null;
if(pathWasSelected == true) 
    selectedPath = dlg.FileName;
```

Comment: Thanks! That was super helpful. Ookii dialog was giving me a ton of troubles with reference issues. WPF's dll plugged in like a charm,

Answer (score 7):

I cannot reproduce this. But maybe there is just some confusion here. If I do this:

```
        var dialog = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog();
        dialog.SelectedPath = @"C:\Data";
        dialog.ShowDialog();
```

It will launch in "C:" having selected the Folder "data". When pressing OK, the result is "C:\Data". However, including the backslash at the end:

```
        var dialog = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog();
        dialog.SelectedPath = @"C:\Data\";
        dialog.ShowDialog();
```

will launch the dialog within this exact folder and selecting nothing by default. When pressing "OK", the result is again "C:\Data".

Answer (score 0):

WpfFolderBrowser.WpfFolderBrowserDialog - this is the one that worked for me best!

I did one fix though:
The function ErrorHelper.HResultFromWin32(int) generate System.OverflowException when pressing "Select Folder" or "Cancel" (run in .NET 4.5.1).

To fix, I put the problematic code in unchecked block:

```
unchecked
{
  win32ErrorCode =
      (int)((win32ErrorCode & 0x0000FFFF) | (FACILITY_WIN32 << 16) | 0x80000000);
}
```

[McNeight/WpfFolderBrowser](https://github.com/McNeight/WpfFolderBrowser)